# ASP.NET - when button click operation takes more than 1 hour gets internet explorer cannot display webpage errror

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7, localhost

I am developing asp.net web application which extracts records from database and rest api.
When click extract button on page, it extracts records and redirects to other page which shows the extracted records.
While redirecting other page, I stored extracted records in session.
Up to 20k records, I haven't face with any issue which takes less than 1 hour. But when I try to extract more than 20k records, I am getting "Internet explorer cannot display webpage" error in middle of extraction without any exception.
I hosted application on server and also tried from my local, result is always same.
I don't make any ajax call.
Can you guys please give me any suggestion?

```
   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" />
    <sessionState timeout="2880" mode="InProc"></sessionState>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="360000000" executionTimeout="360000000"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that letting browser wait for an hour is far from optimal in any case. A far better solution would be to trigger an asynchronous operation and then use AJAX pooling to check if the extraction is complete and after it gets done, redirect.

Comment: I also tried it with AJAX call, I was getting Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The status code returned from the server was: 12002, despite maximum timeout AsyncPostBackTimeout="360000000"

Comment: I think that you should just fire the AJAX request to start the extraction asynchronously (on a new thread for example) and return OK status along with some ID of the operation to the browser. This ID could then be used to pool if the result is ready or not. That means - the operation will be performed without any ties to ASP.NET request pool, and that will also help you make sure that you will not keep many of these long running operations at the same time while preventing new requests to be fulfilled.